# How do you hash a string? I need random strings somehow turned into integers to put them in my hash table

Tags: c++, hashtable, type-conversion, hash

For example, "foobar" should hash to something like 3456. My hash table array has size 811, so my hash function will do 3456 % 811 to find the position in the hash table to place "foobar".

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Comment: @Saeed Amiri: His hash table array has a size of 811. This does not limit it's implementation to 811 strings...

Comment: Answered more comprehensively at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/49550/15162

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a build it stdlib function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
i = atoi(char *);
```

It returns the integer value of that string.

Comment: @delnan: But it is a possible hash method...a possible but very bad one :-)

Comment: I'll have to try that... I want simple, regardless of efficiency. Its only for exercise.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer: why? This seems to be a valid answer regardless of how "bad" it is.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest *djb2* from [Hash Functions](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html)

#### djb2

> this algorithm (k=33) was first reported by dan bernstein many years ago in comp.lang.c. another version of this algorithm (now favored by bernstein) uses xor: `hash(i) = hash(i - 1) * 33 ^ str[i]`; the magic of number 33 (why it works better than many other constants, prime or not) has never been adequately explained.

```
unsigned long hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
```

#### Also of interest

is the **`lose lose`** implementation from the original K&R book quoted. A good example of *how **not** to hash your string.*

Answer (score 0):

Boost Funcional/Hash

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/hash/tutorial.html

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::hash<std::string> string_hash;

    std::size_t h = string_hash("Hash me");

    size_t table_index = h % 811;
}
```

Comment: THat's interesting. I'd like to make an actual (simple) hash function myself though. In reality I'd probably do that, but this is just an exercise.